# Displaying PHP inside HTML div

Tags: php, html

I really need help with displaying PHP inside HTML. 
    Please see the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nq4fxxdg/
    When I inserting it to a PHP file, it is not displaying anything.

```
Would really appreciate your kind help.

Regards,
Yaniv
```

Comment: what's stopping you from doing it? do it like this..
`<div><?php echo "hi"; ?></div>`

Comment: That jsFiddle doesn't really clear anything up.  If you want to show code client-side, then don't wrap it in server tags.  What exactly are you trying to do?  How is it failing?  Be specific.

Answer (score 1):

What's stopping you from doing it? do it like this..
`<div><?php echo "hi"; ?></div>`,

For starters, store the value that needs to be displayed within in variables like this..

```
$mjob = $CORE->_e(array('mjob', '31'));
```

then just echo the value like this..

```
 <div class='buyjobbox text-center'>
  <?php echo $mjob; ?>
  ...... 
  ....
  ...
 </div>
```

You don't have to append whole html code in a variable, instead cho php variables in the html code..

If you are using a function to retrieve values than return those values in an array from the function and then display values within html using that array returned from the function..

What you did was appending whole html php code in a variable `$STRING` and then instead of displaying it with `echo` you returned it as if you are using a function which is an error..you need to use `echo` to display it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Coder anonymous,
I think that this is too complicated for me as this is my first try with PHP...

Comment: Hi @David,
I copied this code from the theme that I am using. It should display a button with a div underneath it.

Comment: I explained in my answer, how to go about it. Please use the same to achieve what you require.

Comment: After  <?php echo $mjob; ?> should I paste the whole PHP code?

Comment: go step by step, first put all the values from php you need to display in variables, and then echo them with in html code as i showed above in my answer..

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a try

Comment: Sure. Also try learning php first from w3schools or something like that..

Comment: Will do that, thanks